# Regular event ID 1315 "ticket supplied was invalid" when not using forms auth

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, forms-authentication

We're seeing lots of events like these even though we have authentication set to "None":

```
Event code: 4005
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid. 
Event time: 12/3/2013 12:50:06 PM 
Event time (UTC): 12/3/2013 6:50:06 PM 
Event ID: 9a0cc0c93a964b1c9bd7126dc367b09b 
Event sequence: 163807 
Event occurrence: 23853 
Event detail code: 50201 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/BG-4-130305700816025855 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /BG 
    Application Path: D:\inetpub\wwwroot\BG\ 
    Machine name: ***
```

I even double-checked in IIS Manager at the site and server level and the GUI shows Forms Authentication set to Disabled.

This is using asp.net 4.0 running on Server 2008 R2.  I tried adding a machineKey to machine.config just to test but it still fails.  It doesn't seem like all requests are failing since I only see the error once a minute but I can't isolate which ones are failing.  I even tried using Fiddler to send a bogus .ASPXAUTH cookie but I didn't see any new errors in the event log that match up with my request.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
tim